# Debugging with var_dump -> where does the output go?

Tags: 7

Me and a colleague had a D7 problem to handle, $_SESSION were being lost for anonymous users.  Because this is all happening on a staging server in a corporate environnment, devel module has been ripped out in preparation for the push to production. My colleague starts inserting `var_dumps()` in a  forms validate function, but the results don't show to screen.

He figures the validation is not being called, but I tell him about how Drupal suppresses output during rendering, I have experienced this many times.  Adding a `die` in the validate function confirmed that the function was in fact being executed,  except the question remains ->  why / how is output suppressed when echoing / var_dumping in functions?

Debugging with var_dump is probably not the most recommended or effective method, I just want to know what it is that prevents ouptput.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the `var_dump()` works but gets hidden below the theme. This is because theme rendering comes last.

I could go into it more, but basically just install [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and use `dpm()` for your variable dumps. It prints them in a Drupal-style message. You'll love it.

Answer (score 0):

you'll see it if you exit execution:

```
var_dump( $your_variable );
exit();
```